# Import keras-js will break unit tests for related functions and components

Tags: reactjs, redux, keras, jasmine, jestjs

I'm using keras-js (https://github.com/transcranial/keras-js) to do some sentiment analysis for user summary at front end. It's working fine for predicting results. But when I run 'yarn test', some test cases are broken due to WebGL2 library used by keras-js.

I've tried to search similar problem, but only found:

It's situated in node_modules/gl/webgl.js.

function checkObject (object) {
  return typeof object === 'object' ||
  !object
}
All I have done is loosen the void check from object === void 0 to !object. Now it runs, at least it can create a gl context.

When I changed above code in keras-js webgl file, all tests passed.

```
import KerasJS from 'keras-js';
let model = new KerasJS.Model({
      filepath: 'imdb_bidirectional_lstm.bin',
      gpu: false
    });
await processPredict(modelArr, caseData, model);
```

The test cases should pass even if import keras-js into my app. But now, it shows error message like:

TypeError: gl.getExtension is not a function

```
   8 |       filepath: 'imdb_bidirectional_lstm.bin',
   9 |       gpu: false
> 10 |     });
     |                  ^
  11 |     await processPredict(modelArr, caseData, model);
  12 |     // for (let k = 0; k < caseData.notes.length; k++) {
  13 |     //   let model = new KerasJS.Model({

  at new WebGL2 (node_modules/keras-js/lib/WebGL2.js:22:12)
  at Object.<anonymous> (node_modules/keras-js/lib/WebGL2.js:320:16)
  at Object.<anonymous> (node_modules/keras-js/lib/Layer.js:8:14)
  at Object.<anonymous> (node_modules/keras-js/lib/layers/InputLayer.js:10:37)
  at Object.<anonymous> (node_modules/keras-js/lib/layers/index.js:16:42)
  at Object.<anonymous> (node_modules/keras-js/lib/Model.js:28:38)
  at Object.<anonymous> (node_modules/keras-js/lib/index.js:22:37)
  at Object.<anonymous> (src/utils/getSentimentAnalysis.ts:10:39)
  at Object.<anonymous> (src/redux/actions/anomalyDataActions.ts:12:29)
  at Object.<anonymous> (src/redux/actions/anomalyDataActions.test.js:11:50)
```

Comment: i think using the keras.js insn't a good idea. because keras.js project is terminated. check the tensorflow.js https://www.tensorflow.org/js

Comment: @Jinguk Kim, Thanks for your advice, but my project is based on Keras, we trained models by using Keras at back end , that's why my manager wants me to use KerasJS. I'll discuss this further with my manager. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

i used the model on the web that trained by Keras.
and i'm also using the Tensorflow.js
it supports using load keras model.
please check out. :)

Comment: Thanks, I'll try.